# Consulta no MySQL não ordena corretamente

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela de jogos chamada `game`, uma tabela de plataformas de jogos chamada `plataformas` e uma tabela que faz o relacionamento N-para-N entre as duas chamada `game_plataforma`.

Tenho uma consulta que tem que buscar uma plataforma de jogos, mas tem que ordenar de acordo com o último jogo que foi cadastrado nela.

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
select DISTINCT(p.id), p.slug, p.nome,gp.id_plataforma
                                from game g
                                join game_plataforma gp on g.id=gp.id_game
                                join plataformas p on gp.id_plataforma=p.id
                                where g.ativo='1'
                                group by p.nome
                                order by g.dia DESC
                                limit 4
```

Só que não está ordenando corretamente. Ele esta ordenando alfabeticamente pelo nome da plataforma.

Fiz o seguinte teste:

```
select id_plataforma from game_plataforma order by id DESC;
```

E ele retornou certo esses valores abaixo para o campo `id_plataforma`:

> 2, 22, 2, 25, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 25, 2, 1, 2, 2, 23, 6, 6, 22, 2, 22

Agora, quando executo esse aqui:

```
select distinct(id_plataforma) from game_plataforma order by id DESC;
```

Ele volta isso aqui para os mesmos campos:

> 25, 1, 23, 6, 2, 22

E com `group by` dá nisso:

```
select id_plataforma from game_plataforma group by id_plataforma order by id DESC;
```

> 25, 1, 23, 6, 2, 22

Eu estou ficando louco ou tem alguma coisa errada?

Estrutura da tabela `game_plataforma`:

[image: estrutura]

o que preciso que venha são os ids de plataforma nesta ordem:

> 2, 22, 25, 1, 23

Comment: Sua pergunta está um tanto confusa. Além de um monte de números de ids, o que há na tabela `game_plataforma`? Ela é uma tabela de junção de um relacionamente N-para-N entre as tabelas `plataformas` e `game`? Você diz que tem que buscar a categoria, mas não tem nenhum campo na sua query chamado "categoria" ou que sugira ser uma categoria. Ou por acaso, por categoria você quis dizer plataforma? Enfim, diga ao menos quais são os campos de cada tabela e se possível mostre alguns dos dados que nelas estão.

Comment: a categoria he a plataforma e sim o game_plataforma he uma tabela relacional de n para n vou mandar um ss do que tem nela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comecemos por essa consulta aqui:

```
select id_plataforma from game_plataforma order by id DESC;
```

Observe que você está selecionando um campo enquanto está ordenando por um outro campo. Não deve ser isso o que você queria. O campo `id` que ele usa para ordenar é apenas a ordem de inserção dos registros nessa tabela. Isso vai trazer apenas uma lista de ids de plataformas que estão relacionadas a algum jogo qualquer o número de vezes em que estejam relacionados e ordenados de acordo com a ordem em que foram inseridos. Isso não vai trazer nada de útil para você.

Já essa consulta aqui:

```
select distinct(id_plataforma) from game_plataforma order by id DESC;
```

Isso trás algo parecido com a consulta anterior, mas sem repetições. Uma lista de ids de plataformas que estejam relacionadas a algum jogo qualquer ao menos uma vez, ordenadas de acordo com a ordem em que foram inseridas. Também não é algo lá muito útil.

```
select id_plataforma from game_plataforma group by id_plataforma order by id DESC;
```

Esse `group by` vai ser apenas uma forma bizarra de se fazer o `distinct` da consulta anterior.

Bem, vamos deixar esses testes de lado e olhar a sua consulta original:

```
select DISTINCT(p.id), p.slug, p.nome,gp.id_plataforma
                            from game g
                            join game_plataforma gp on g.id=gp.id_game
                            join plataformas p on gp.id_plataforma=p.id
                            where g.ativo='1'
                            group by p.nome
                            order by g.dia DESC
                            limit 4
```

Você está listando dados de plataformas, mas acaba indo até a tabela de jogos para buscá-los. Se não fosse pelo `group by` e pelo `distinct`, o número de resultados seria provavelmente o número de registros na tabela `game_plataforma`, o que significa várias vezes as mesmas plataformas multiplicadas pelos número de jogos ativos em cada plataforma.

Além disso, parece que você não entende como funciona o `DISTINCT`. O `DISTINCT` se aplica a todo o conjunto de colunas selecionadas, e não apenas a essa que está entre parênteses. Aliás, esses parênteses não estão fazendo absolutamente nada.

Acho que o que você queria no fim das contas é isso:

```
SELECT p.id, p.slug, p.nome
FROM game g
INNER JOIN game_plataforma gp ON g.id = gp.id_game
INNER JOIN plataformas p ON gp.id_plataforma = p.id
WHERE g.ativo = '1'
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY MAX(gp.id) DESC
```

O truque aqui é que você quer só informações de plataformas, mas tal como na sua consulta original, precisa ir navegando até a tabela de jogos para lá pegar o campo `ativo` (o que também já elimina as plataformas para as quais não há jogos). Isso daí iria repetir as informações de plataformas, não fosse pelo nosso `GROUP BY`.

Para o `GROUP BY` funcionar, é importante que nenhum campo das tabelas `gp` ou `g` apareça no `SELECT` ou no `ORDER BY` sem usar-se alguma função agregadora. Caso contrário, eles iriam bagunçar com o `GROUP BY` que joga todas elas em um só registro. O propósito das funções agregadoras é exatamente a de juntar vários registros em um só para poderem ser usados quando há um `GROUP BY`.

Entretanto, para fazer a ordenação no `ORDER BY` eu preciso de uma informação da tabela `gp` (qual é a mais recente), e portanto, eu preciso de alguma função agregadora. A função agregadora usada no `ORDER BY` é a função `MAX` que escolhe o maior valor dentre todos aqueles que serão agregados, no caso o maior `id` da tabela `gp`. Como os `id`s estão ordenados por ordem de inserção, então o maior `id` é o mais recente.

Comment: Incrível é isso mesmo . pode me explicar melhor como chegou nisso pois o que quero fazer é criar abas que se ordenem  de acordo com as ultimas postagens de games nas plataformas

Comment: haha cara deu certo muito obrigado mesmo olha ai como ficou http://desapegogames.com.br/ ( logo abaixo do banner de bem vindo nas abas )

Comment: @JasarOrion Atualizei a resposta com a explicação. ;)

Comment: @JasarOrion Ah, e por sinal, achei interessante o seu site. ;)

Comment: entendi um pouco me deu uma clareada boa . muito obrigado agradeço a ajuda.